# How to round numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, rounding

Assume:

1.5 round to 2
1.9 round to 2
1.4 round to 1
2.49 round to 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use round function

```
  select convert(int,(ROUND(1.9,0)))
```

Comment: The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: @LongHoàngNguyễn have you tried it ? btw your dbms name please

Comment: That depends on DBMS you use (which you never told us). For example, as far as Oracle is concerned, `round(2.49)` is just fine. So - which database do you use? Now you know the function, check its syntax and fix it yourself.

Comment: I'm use SQL Server 2014. I'm Tried round(2.49) and error The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: I think this function is not supported in sql and probably has to write a private function roundup and rounddown based on its own algorithm.

Comment: @LongHoàngNguyễn check answer edited and please tag your question as a sql server dbms

Comment: @LongHoàngNguyễn does any problem in answer ?

Comment: No! Thank you very much